# What does "length of acquaintance" means?

Tags: meaning, questions

My (non-English) teacher encountered this question in a recommendation form and asked me for it's meaning. Does this mean how long I've known someone, or how close I am with him?
It'd be awesome if you could give me a sample response to a question that asks me about the length of my acquaintance with someone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means how long have you known him.

Comment: +1 for @Hotlicks, i.e. duration of relationship. For example: *Length of Engagement and of Acquaintance: It might be thought that there would be no particular correlation the length of acquaintance and the length of engagement*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What does 'length of acquaintance' mean?" It means, **"How long have you known this person?"** An appropriate answer would be something like this: **"I've known him for about two years."** Or, if you are more than mere acquaintances, you might say, **"He and I have been friends for several years."** Usually, one only asks about "length of acquaintance" if the person asking doesn't know what the nature of your relationship is with the other person.